# Regression when dependent variable is the difference betwen two proportions

Tags: r, regression, repeated-measures, proportion, glmm

Here is some sample data:

```
structure(list(
y.t2 = c(NaN, 0.05, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1), 
n.t2 = c(0, 231, 228, 219, 210, 175, 250, 255, 270, 257), 
y.t3 = c(0.07, 0.11, 0.2, 0.19, 0.17, 0.12, 0.18, 0.23, 0.18, NaN), 
n.t3 = c(226, 224, 223, 208, 206, 224, 228, 246, 233, 0), 
x = c(-6, 0, 2.7, -0.1, -2.4, -2.5, -1.5, -0.4, 0.3, -0.3), 
diff = c(NaN, 0.06, 0.18, 0.17, 0.15, 0.08, 0.12, 0.18, 0.11, NaN)), 
.Names = c("y.t2", "n.t2", "y.t3", "n.t3", "x", "diff"), 
row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

`y` was measured at times `t2` and `t3`. I used `glm` like:

```
summary(glm(y.t2~x,binomial,my.df,n.t2))
summary(glm(y.t3~x,binomial,my.df,n.t3))
```

to test the effect of `x` on `y` from two time points, `t2` and `t3`. But if I want to test the effect of `x` on the difference, as in, `y.t3-y.t2`, how do I go about it? Though in my case, I always expect a positive difference (to use `glm` with logit link), in theory, it can be negative as well, ranging between -1 and 1.

Do I do a linear regression then, or what method would be appropriate in this case? I want to do `diff~x`.
I am also wondering about the weights argument. Some subjects dropped out and new ones joined between time `t2` and time `t3`; the number of cases varies between the two instances.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about analyzing the data would be via a generalized linear mixed model, glmm.  The time point would be included as a fixed effect and at the very least you could allow a random intercept to account for observing an individual at multiple time points.  In addition, this would enable you to include an interaction between time and x if you think there is a possibility that the effect of x changes over time.  This method would also be able to accommodate the pattern of missingness resulting from dropouts and new subjects, assuming that the data are MAR (missing at random), a standard assumption.